What can I do about Overfitting in Tabular Data Model
I've built a predictive model for predicting outcomes based on certain features in the supplied data.
The model is a tabular learner utilizing fastai.
The dataset consists of about 300 records split for training, validation and testing sets.
I've implemented techniques to address overfitting such as early stopping and weight decay, but the model still appears to be overfitting when evaluated on unseen data.
Furthermore, I've also tried to adjust hyperparameters such as learning rate and batch size without improvement. I suspect there might be some aspects of my model's architecture or preprocessing pipeline that could be contributing to the problem, but I'm not sure where to start investigating.
Given the sensitive nature of the project, I'm unable to provide specific details about the dataset or the prediction task, but I can share the preprocessing and structure of the model as it currently stands.
Here's output of the training:



epoch
train_loss
valid_loss
accuracy
time




0
0.752707
0.579501
0.776119
00:00


1
0.699270
0.833771
0.776119
00:00


2
0.652438
0.598243
0.791045
00:00


3
0.621083
3.889398
0.776119
00:00


4
0.591348
0.632366
0.791045
00:00


5
0.580582
6.670314
0.791045
00:00




No improvement since epoch 2: early stopping

Here's the code for preprocessing (after I've built features which I can't divulge).
The features list defines each feature including a valid value range and weights (feature, range_, and weight as used in the normalize function below).
def custom_normalize(df, feature, range_, weight):
    df[feature] = normalize(df[feature], range_)
    df[feature] = df[feature] * weight
    return df

splits = RandomSplitter(valid_pct=0.2)(range_of(df))

procs = [Categorify, FillMissing]

for feature, info in features.items():
    # Determine a range within which to select values when training.
    procs.append(partial(custom_normalize, feature=feature, range_=info['range'], weight=info['weight']))

Building the model and training is pretty standard as far as I know:
to = TabularPandas(df, procs=procs,
                   cat_names = cat_vars,
                   cont_names = cont_vars,
                   y_names=dep_var,
                   splits=splits)

dls = to.dataloaders(bs=64)

early_stop = EarlyStoppingCallback(monitor='accuracy', min_delta=0.01, patience=3)

learn = tabular_learner(dls, metrics=accuracy, wd=0.1)
learn.lr_find()

# Plot learning rate.
learn.recorder.plot_lr_find()

# Choose a learning rate based on the plot.
lr = learn.recorder.lrs[np.argmin(learn.recorder.losses)]

learn.fit_one_cycle(15, lr, cbs=early_stop)
learn.show_results()

# Only save model if none exists
# TODO wrap save in conditional that prevents saving if a model exists.
if not os.path.exists(model_fname):
    learn.save(model_fname)


how do you know this is overfitting problem?

One thing that helps me a lot and you might missing, is a Pearson correlation check. This will give you a report (I prefer matrix) where you can realize if there's a correlation between some of your features. Heavily related features, will greatly infect your model and make it prone to overfitting. Related/Correlated features, should be removed.
Although I have a lot of experience with Python, in regards to Machine/Deep Learning I feel more comfortable with R. I'll try to give both versions.
The code is something that :
In R:
#Pearson correlation
# Cherry-pick only numeric data and do a correlation matrix
numeric_data <- data[, sapply(data, is.numeric)]
correlation_matrix <- cor(numeric_data, method = "pearson")
print(correlation_matrix)

And Python:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Assuming 'data' is your DataFrame containing the dataset
# Cherry-pick only numeric data and do a correlation matrix
numeric_data = data.select_dtypes(include=[np.number])  # Selects only numeric columns

# Calculate the Pearson correlation matrix
correlation_matrix = numeric_data.corr(method='pearson')

# Print the correlation matrix
print(correlation_matrix)

Another pitfall might be feature normalization. Depending on your data you might have to scale any numeric features. An example is the following. Here I am doing min-max. The type of scaling usually depends on your data:
In R:
# Doing Min-Max scaling
scaled_features <- as.data.frame(lapply(numerical_features, rescale))

The code in Python (using pandas):
scaled_features = pd.DataFrame(scaler.fit_transform(numerical_features), columns=numerical_features.columns)

Could you please try those and give me feedback? In general, I believe that everything in ML/DL is about Feature Engineering and Preprocessing. Let the Data speak and guide you.

This seems counterintuitive. For example, if you're trying to determine why your car isn't braking as effectively anymore, you'd check the brakes and see if the brake discs need some attention. You'd use related features to solve the problem - but now it's causing problems? Very weird if I'm understanding correctly.

@Ortund I am sorry that my answer doesn't help. Given the fact that dataset details cannot be public, I thought that these general steps might help. Maybe I misunderstood your question and what kind of help you are asking for.

No, no, your answer is great; it gives me more things to consider that I didn't know about before. You've provided plenty here that I can learn about and research to expand my knowledge on the matter. I'm very grateful, thank you :)
